# Colour fading strawberry

Tags: strawberries

Someone brought me some strawberries. After washing and wrapping in facial tissue, I found red color in the tissue. My question is **will natural strawberry color do that?** Or was the color painted on to make the strawberries good looking?

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/23808/are-strawberries-really-dyed

Comment: Unfortunately, there really isn't a good answer on the related question (at least to this question), and this question really asks something different. If the question is "will undyed strawberries stain tissue?", then it is not a duplicate of the related question.

Comment: It is impossible to know whether it is dye or not unless we get some guidance on where you live. Some countries have regulations regarding dyeing strawberries and others do not.

Comment: It could be helpful to know where you live, as Catija mentioned. If possible, a photograph of the strawberry and tissue would also be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

I have certainly seen red come off when drying strawberries I've grown myself. But I don't normally dry them (I don't even wash them unless they're dirty).